# Ошибка при работе с box2d

Tags: c++, box2d

Есть код:

```cpp
#include <box2d/box2d.h>

int main()
{
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, 9.8f);
    b2World world(gravity);

    
    return 0;
}
```

Но при завершении программы в Visual Studio вылетает исключение:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'world' was corrupted.
```

Comment: @user7860670, поправил, проблема с box2d

Comment: В таком случае следует смотреть в процесс сборки box2d, компилятор, настройки и заголовочные файлы должны быть именно такими, какие используются в проекте.

Comment: у себя на машине скомпилировал пример (правда убрал лишнюю точку с запятой в первой строке, но я не думаю, что это что то меняет) и все запустилось.  Но я это на gcc+linux делал

Comment: скорее всего я неправильно собрал box2d, так как у меня world занимает 102024 байт